# Echo array by Key PHP

Tags: php, arrays

ARRAY

I need some help to output this array

```
$a = array(
  ""._CHOOSE_=> '-Escoje Una ',
  ""._ANY_=> 'Any',
  "1" => "Español",
  "2" => "Ingles",
  "3" => "Frances",
  "4" => "Italiano",
  "5" => "portugues",
  "6" => "Chino",
  ""._NDISCLOSED_ => ''
);
```

example php code

```
echo ('array_values($a, 2)'); // I need this to return ENGLISH from the arry
```

can some one help me with this.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 echo $a['ENGLISH'];
```

This is how you echo values based on keys.

Comment: English/Ingles is the value not key. In his question; 2 is the key

Comment: he has association but in a different way..I modified my answer though

Answer (score 2):

```
echo $a["2"]
```

is what you're looking for

BTW you don't need to do something like

```
""._CHOOSE_
```

as long as *CHOOSE* is a string, you can simply write

```
_CHOOSE_ => '-Escoje Una '
```

Comment: I have multiple array I need to pull as an example  English  witch is #2  from array $a

Comment: @paisapimp you're trying to select what exactly? the "english" string? Or the index?

Comment: I get the #2 from the mysql and I need to show english as result of #2

Comment: @paisapimp so my answer is right. Just "substitute" the hard-coded "2" with whatever you're obtaining from db

Comment: this work for me.. thanks a lot  echo $a["2"]

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case you will need to type the echo like this:

`echo $a['1']` where `'1'` is key for your array.